# Laravel created_by/modified_by relations

Tags: laravel-4, model, eloquent

I was trying to get this working in a typical `belongsTo` relation. However it keeps saying that the column is not set in the model, even if looking in the actual database it is there.

I have tried to look at the source code as well as try many approaches to bypass this issue, however nothing seems to do anything.

```
public function modifiedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\Users\Model\User', 'modified_by');
}

public function createdBy() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\Users\Model\User', 'created_by');
}
```

This is the code inside the model, I use PSR-0 to define modules, better splitting up logic (no issues with that) but using this it would give an error of

`Undefined property: \Modules\Module\Model\CurrentModel::$modified_by`

This is coming from a seed to push some initial info into the database.

```
$user = Sentinel::findById(1);
$model = new CurrentModel;
$model->modifiedBy()->associate($user);
$model->save();
```

This is basically how it goes together, I have tried for some time to figure out what is wrong but I am calling blanks. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't say there's no column in the table, but there's no property on the object. And that is pretty much impossible with `Eloquent\Model`, so check the stacktrace and find out where that error happens.

Comment: I am using artisan to get this error, have not build this functionality into the application yet because I do not have any test data. Is there any way to get the stack trace via artisan?

Comment: Make sure you have `debug => true` for the environment you're running artisan in.

Comment: It is added, so if artisan shows a stack trace in debug mode that would mean that is the only error in the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution. Not a fix though but I would consider this an issue with laravel so I may look into adding it as a bug report (although this could be fixed in laravel 5?).

Basically with modified_by I need to define the column it is using and not let laravel automatically generate it (in order to do this "cleanly"). However the "bug" (only calling it a bug as currently I can only see this as an unintended problem) makes it so you cannot define the column it will be using, you have to let laravel decide it for you.

So I changed the functions to look like this:

```
public function modifiedby()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\Modules\Users\Model\User');
}
```

This makes laravel assume the column is `modifiedby_id`, but by changing my migrations to reflect that there was no more error.

Comment: In short - no way :) You must have done something wrong, somewhere else.

Comment: Well all the code I have shown is everything that relates to this, so its somewhere hidden in this :P. Don't got the time to fight with it so if this is how I have to do it then so be it, might be cleaner looking to just have modified_by but if it has to be modifiedby_id then meh, i can live with it. If anyone has an actual fix then I will mark that the answer ^^.